# sscanf format trouble avoiding :

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

I've got to split **(with sscanf yes or yes)** a char* with this format:

`First_Line1: This is the 1st line`
or
`First_Line: This-is_the_first-line123`

I just need to put the content in 2 variables, one with the content before the ":" and the other one with the content after ":".

Please note that there might be numbers and special characters before and after the ":".

Some examples I've tried so far are:

```
sscanf(cab, "%[a-zA-Z]%*[:] %[a-zA-Z]", &cab.name, &cab.value);
sscanf(cab, "%s %*[:] %s", &cab.name, &cab.value);
```

and A LOT more I can't remember. (I don't care about special characters actually, just want to split it in two)

I can't make it work properly with any format parameter. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, then we will suggest how to change it. People don't like being expected to write the whole thing.

Comment: Consider using `strtok` on a whole line.

Comment: Sorry, just did it right now. I've tried with many formats I can't even remember all of them

Comment: Need to see some code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never even used this format before but I soon worked out this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char inp [] = "one two: three four";
    char str1[100] = "";
    char sep = ' ';
    char str2[100] = "";

    if (sscanf(inp, "%[^:]%c %[^\0]", str1, &sep, str2) != 3)
        return 1;

    printf("'%s'\n", str1);
    printf("'%s'\n", str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output (the `'` are added to clearly show the extent of the strings):

```
'one two'
'three four'
```

Please note one particular error of yours: `&cab.name` etc should not have the `&` since the value you supply will either be, or decay to, a pointer.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @user3121023 (comments since deleted), the format`%[^\0]` will prematurely terminate the format string. So I suggest using a character that *does not appear* in the input data. Since it is never found, the rest of the input is taken.

```
if (sscanf(inp, "%[^:]%c %[^\7]", str1, &sep, str2) != 3)
    return 1;
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much

Comment: @user3121023 thanks for your remarks, please see my **Edit**.